# Мнение независимых пользователей

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Пожалуйста найдите минутку и оцените. Сравните, насколько сильно я накосячил (кроме элементов, которых нет)?.

Оригинал

[image: Оригинал]

Верстка

[image: Верстка]

Comment: что бы сравнить 2 скриншота наложите их друг на друга в Ps и верхний сделайте прозрачным

Comment: спасибо, но это не совсем подходит для резиновой (%) верстки

Comment: Ха, знакомый движ) @Eli, чисто ради интересно, за идею верстаете?)

Comment: да, попросил знакомый, я правда тоже далеко не мастер, но старался....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С отступами что-то явно напутал (сверху margin больше надо), после "запомнить" пробел откусил, кнопка больше должна быть вроде.

Вообще есть в Фотошопе инструмент "линейка" - размеры шрифтов и блоков замерять.

Размер оригинала меньше.

Да и вообще оригинальный сайт (или скрин) - заточен под JavaScript с jQuery, сложных элементов чистой (css - html) верстки нет.

Comment: линейка+калькулятор для резиновой верстки?

Comment: ну да - сначала все в пикселах считается, а потом переводится в 'em' относительно родительского блока 

Но с резиновой вёрсткой мороки много